# Converse of Borel-Lebesgue in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

**Question:**

If every open cover of a set $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ admits a finite subcover, then $X$ is compact.

**Note:**

**Definition**: $X$ is said to be a compact set is if $X$ is bounded and closed.

**Attempt:**

- $X$ is bounded.

Suppose that $X$ is not bounded. Then for each $k \in \mathbb N$ we would be able to find $x_k \in X$ such that $\|x_k\| > k$. Then if we took $B_k = B(0; k)$ we would have that $X \not \subset B_k$ and consequently the open cover

$$X \subset \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb N} B_k$$

wouldn't admit a finite subcover (because $\mathbb N$ is not bounded above), which is a contradiction. Therefore $X$ must be bounded.

- $X$ is closed.

In fact, if it was the contrary there would be a sequence of points $x_k \in X$ such that

$$\lim_{k \in \mathbb N} x_k = a \not\in X$$

thus for each $k \in \mathbb N$ we could take $B\big[a; \frac{1}{k}\big]$, then $A_k = \mathbb R^n - B\big[a;\frac{1}{k}\big]$  would be open and

$$X \subset \mathbb R^n-\{a\} \subset \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb N} A_k$$

the cover wouldn't admit a finite subcover (ortherwise $\mathbb R^n - \{a\}$ would be bounded). Therefore $X$ must be closed.

*Conclusion:* $X$ is compact.

I'm not entirely confident if this is correct. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that I may have phrased differently, but the ideas are all there. Your proof looks fine.

Comment: Would you mind to say what?Is there anything wrong?

Comment: One thing about style: in the first part of the proof you chose $x_k$ so that they lie outside of $B(0;k)$. That's very nice. In the second part of the proof, it is not true that $x_k$ lies outside of $A_k$. The symmetry is lost. But like I said, nothing is "wrong". At worst they are just not "pretty".

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, really appreciate it.